# How to create dynamic TypeScript types that are connected in different functions

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am looking for some help with TypeScript Type definitions. I have two functions. One is called `register` and one is called `dispatch`. The types are dependent on each other that's why typehinting should be depending on them.

To the definition of the functions:

**Register** can register events on a custom-type ('Products'). The type can be written manually and isn't predefined. In this case we defined Product-Events. So for a product you can add and delete.

```
register('Products', {
    add(product: Product) {...},
    delete(productId: string) {...},
})
```

Then we have the **dispatch** function. This one should automatically only allow the events that are registered for that type.

```
dispatch('Products', 'add', payload)
```

What would be the best way to tackle that problem? Should the functions be built up differently to make it easier?

Things I have tried so far:

- I adapted register to take one argument (my Product object) with the name and tried to generate types out of it. Although I am having troubles with mapping the name in the dispatch to the type so only the relevant values are passed

```
interface Register {
    name: string;
}

const Product = {
    name: 'Product',
    add() {console.log('adding')},
    delete() {console.log('deleting')},
}

const ProductGroup = {
    name: 'ProductGroup',
    create() {console.log('creating')},
    update() {console.log('updating')},
}

type RegisterTypes = 
  | keyof typeof Product
  | keyof typeof ProductGroup;

type DispatchProductTypes = keyof typeof Product

export function register(register: Register): any {}
export function dispatch(name: string, method: RegisterTypes, ...args: any): any {}

register(Product)
dispatch('Product', 'delete', {});
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This is not possible yet. However, if you redesign your `dispatch` function's API to accept objects instead of a string, then it will be possible.

Comment: @hittingonme thanks a lot for your quick response. How would the object that you pass to the `dispatch` function look like? Would you just wrap the arguments in an object? And how do I connect the type definitions then so only eg Product ones are allowed?

Comment: Is is possible to do but than you should make `register` and `dispatch` part of one data structure. I mean these functions should be methods of one class. Does it work for you ?